# Is there a hash function that bins points in same interval to the same hash, so we can identify containing interval in O(1) time

Tags: hash, geometry, geospatial

Let's say we have an interval [1,5], and we've partitioned it into three sub-intervals: [1,2), [2,4), [4,5].

I would like to know if there is a hashing algorithm/function h(x) such that h(a)=h(b) iff a,b are in the same partition.

Does there exist a similar function for higher dimensions, like a 2-d non-uniform partition over some rectangle?

I can think of simple algorithms that work off of ranks along each dimension, but those require O(NM) operations.

My hope is that, at a minimum, I can identify an N-dimensional partition with O(N) operations (assuming that a 1-dimensoinal hash function exists as I outlined above).

Even better would be a multivariate hash function so I can identify the n-dimensional partition in O(1).

Comment: This does not seem possible in general. Because your partition contains information (such as the interval sizes, 1, 2, 1). This information needs to be somehow incorporated in the hash, and this takes a hash function with several free parameters. The resulting expression will cost at least O(N) for evaluation. The situation is much worse in the multidimensional case (the region borders can have arbitrary shape), unless the partition is separable.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks — I suspected it’s not possible. Do you happen to know of the something close to this? Basically trying to map a point to an area. Thinking a kd-tree or similar structure might be best one can do.

Comment: What you are after is relying on the idea of "spatial coherence". (By the way, the main goal of a hash function is to destroy any coherence.) Yes, kD-trees. To some extent octrees, grids or binary space partitioning trees. Closer to O(log(N)).